# Android and Jess Expert system integration

Tags: android, android-studio, expert-system, jess

Is it possible to run jess file(.CLP) in android studio? if someone have done, please help me our give me Link of ant tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, running an expert system on an Android device doesn't make sense, what I would do is create the expert system as a command line tool that runs on a server and returns an output, that output is then sent back to the Android application in a suitable format to be processed on the device and presented to the user.